# Get all subordinates based on line manager marker

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have an employees table that holds an employeeID, Name...etc.... and intLineManager. intLine manager is the employeeID of your line manager. Something like this, with Dave being the top boss with no manager.

```
intEmpID |Name|intLineManager
1        |Dave| NULL
2        |Sue |1
3        |Mike|1
4        |Matt|2
5        |Sara|3
6        |Paul|4
```

I'm looking for an SQL script that will return all employees that are underneath a person.
So a search on Mike will return Sara, a search on Sue will return Matt + Paul and finally a search on Dave will return everyone.

Comment: Take a look at recursive ctes. This is exactly what they are designed to do. There are hundreds and hundreds of examples all over SO and millions across the internet.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: This question shows no research attempt.

Comment: Thanks Sean and A RedFearn. now that I know that the technique is called recursive ctes I, can not only use the answer below for this one issue but, can also look in to the concept as a whole for when I need it use it again in the furture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `CTE` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employees(EmpID int, Name varchar(10), LineManager int NULL)
INSERT INTO #Employees VALUES
(1, 'Dave', NULL), 
(2, 'Sue', 1), 
(3, 'Mike', 1), 
(4, 'Matt', 2), 
(5, 'Sara', 3), 
(6, 'Paul', 4)

;WITH CTE as 
(
        SELECT EmpID, Name, LineManager
        FROM #Employees     
        WHERE EmpID = 2 --Sue

        UNION ALL

        SELECT e.EmpID, e.Name, e.LineManager
        FROM #Employees AS E
        INNER JOIN CTE AS C ON c.EmpID = e.LineManager
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
where EmpID > (SELECT TOP 1 EmpID FROM CTE)
ORDER BY EmpID
```

Result for sue(EmpID 2)

```
EmpID       Name       LineManager
----------- ---------- -----------
4           Matt       2
6           Paul       4
```